# Individual mail sending does not work while mailing within loop works

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I have created a function that sends mail to my email id using different mail ids. The setting of the different mail ids are stored in mailpresets table. The problem is that when I send the mails using loop, the mails are received.

```
<cffunction name="processFormSubmission">
    <cfset template = model("mailpreset").findAll() />
    <cfloop query="template">
        <cfmail from="#template.fromEmail#" to="test@test.com" 
                  server="#template.serverHostName#" 
                  username="#template.serverUserName#" 
                  port="#template.serverPort#" 
                  password="#template.serverPassword#" 
                  subject="Mail from #template.fromEmail#" 
                  type="html" 
                  usessl="#template.useSSL#" usetls="#template.useTLS#">

                #template.fromEmail#
            </cfmail>
        </cfloop>
        <cfabort>
    </cffunction>
```

But when I use single mail preset for sending mail the mail  does not get sent.
The mail get send with the same mailpreset when send using the previous method.

```
<cffunction name="processFormSubmission">
    <cfset template = model("mailpreset").findAll(where="id=7") />

    <cfmail from="#template.fromEmail#" to="test@test.com" 
            server="#template.serverHostName#" 
            username="#template.serverUserName#" 
            port="#template.serverPort#" 
            password="#template.serverPassword#" 
            subject="Mail from #template.fromEmail#" 
            type="html" usessl="#template.useSSL#" 
            usetls="#template.useTLS#">

            #template.fromEmail#
    </cfmail>

    <cfabort>
</cffunction>
```

What is the problem behind it?

Comment: The second set of code is cut off, are you sure that 'template' is being set correctly? Do you see the mail in the mail spool? Is there an entry in the mail log? You could wrap a catch-try around the single mail, fire it off to a log, and see if it trips something

Comment: who knows?  What's in your mail log?  Are the mails ending up in your ColdFusion undelivered mail folder, or are they being bounced back by your SMTP server?  In your code your 2nd example doesn't include `<cfset template = model("mailpreset").findAll() />` - are you still doing that?  Also you should var-scope all variables inside your functions, i.e. `template`

Comment: FYI: Fixed code formatting so the second example is fully visible.

Comment: Are you certain that `model("mailpreset").findAll(where="id=7")` is actually returning a proper template? When you call `findAll()` is the template with the ID of 7 returned? Maybe there is a problem with the data.

Comment: Try dumping Template to the page to see if it is set correctly